# How we can define constant in template.php for our theme

Tags: theming, hooks

I want to define some constant for my theme like theme path etc. How i can achieve that.

For module we can define like this

```
define(THEME_PATH, drupal_get_path('theme', 'xyz'));
```

But it is undefined in theme. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the preprocess function (hook_preprocess_THEME), you can use this:

```
$variables['theme_path'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'xyz');
```

Which you can then use as $theme_path in your template.

Comment: Or even better, stick it in the global `hook_preprocess`, not a specific preprocess, and then it's available in every template